# Multibit : transferring coins between local wallets

Tags: wallet, multibit, local

I've created a second local wallet in my multibit. The first wallet is aimed for receiving and sending coins, while the second one is aimed to separate savings.
Is there a way to transfer coins between these two local wallets without paying fees ?
It is possible in a normal bank account but the fees here are really too big.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the coins to an address in your second wallet.  MultiBit maintains each wallet as a separate file on disk, so there is no interaction between them.  One suggestion (which is how I handle this) is to wait until your wallet reaches a large enough amount and then make a single send request to your savings address.  This bundles multiple input transactions into a single output transaction with a single fee.